# Microsoft Access - Calling upon a separate table to define a date range in a query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to Access and am trying to learn as I go.

I have a table that tracks the amount of consumables used that day and there could be multiple entries for one day. For example, it looks like

```
   Date    | Consumable x | Consumable y 
'8/24/2017'|     '4'      |     '3'
'8/24/2017'|     '6'      |     '1'
```

I have a second table that defines my weeks. For example, it looks like

```
WeekID | WeekCounter | WeekStartDate | WeekEndDate 
 '1'   |  'Week 1'   |   '1/4/2017'  | '1/10/2017'
```

I want to make a query that can sum all of the consumables for each week, based on the range defined in the week table. The end product should look like:

```
   Week  | Consumable x | Consumable y 
'Week 20'|    '24'      |    '44'
'Week 21'|    '30'      |    '41'
```

I have tried a number of different approaches but am not confident with anything I have tried. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: You could add a field to your query like:  XX: Format([dateadded],"ww")  which would convert your date to a Week Number. Then use a GROUP BY on the Week #. Not sure if that will give you the week breakdown you want. Remember that you can't have your 'date' field in the query as a 'Group By'

Comment: I have tried that but there is already a system to count set up which I cannot change (External reporting outside of Access) If I had a way to control the Access week number that would work but I do not know how to.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
Select
    WeekCounter As Week,
    Sum([Consumable x]) As TotalX,
    Sum([Consumable y]) As TotalY
From
    TableConsume,
    TableWeek
Where
    TableConsume.Date Between WeekStartDate And WeekEndDate
Group By
    WeekCounter
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a subquery.  Something along these lines:

```
SELECT SUM([Consumable x]) AS SumX, SUM([Consumable Y]) AS SumY, Week FROM
(SELECT Table1.[Consumable x], Table1.[Consumable y], Table2.[Week] FROM
table1 inner join table2 on table1.mydate >= table2.WeekStartDate and table1.mydate <= table2.WeekEndDate)
GROUP BY Week
```

I note you have week 1 as 4th Jan to 10th Jan, so I presume you actually have the WeekEndDate as 23:59:59 (ie 1 second to midnight).  The alternative is to have your week table with dates 7 days apart, and then change the <= table2.WeekEndDate to simply < table2.WeekEndDate.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am trying this out and have a question. What is mydate? You used it twice in the inner loop. Should that actually be table1.date?

Comment: It is just the name of your date column in the table with the consumables.  I always avoid using reserved words (like Date) as the name of columns, since otherwise you always have to surround it with [].  It is not advisable to use reserved words - it's not just me!

Answer (score 0):

You could use this method.  Like @Jonathan I've used `dDate` rather than `Date` for the same reasons (reserved words).

This can only be viewed in SQL and not Design view as Access can't represent the join.

```
SELECT      WeekCounter
            , NZ(SUM(Consumable_X),0) AS C_X
            , NZ(SUM(Consumable_Y),0) AS C_Y
FROM        WeekDefinition LEFT JOIN Consumables ON WeekDefinition.WeekStartDate<=Consumables.dDate AND
                                                    WeekDefinition.WeekEndDate>=Consumables.dDate
GROUP BY    WeekCounter, WeekID
ORDER BY    WeekID
```

---

I'd have to question your reasoning behind the Consumables table though:
At the moment you've got Consumable X and Consumable Y in different fields.  What happens over the years as you add Coonsumables A, B, C & Z?  Each time you'll have to update your table and each query to count the new consumable.

Wouldn't it be better to change the table to hold three fields:  Date, Consumable_Type and Consumable_Amount (you may want to add another field to create a primary key).
Your records would hold values such as:
`'8/24/17' | 'Consumable X' | '4'` and `'8/24/17' | 'Consumable Y' | '3'`

Your query would then look like this:

```
SELECT      WeekCounter
            , Consumable_Type
            , SUM(Consumable_Amount) AS Total
FROM        WeekDefinition LEFT JOIN Consumables ON WeekDefinition.WeekEndDate>=[Consumables].dDate AND 
                                                    WeekDefinition.WeekStartDate<=[Consumables].dDate
GROUP BY    WeekCounter, WeekID, Consumable_Type
ORDER BY    WeekID
```

A cross-tab query would return the table as you want:

```
TRANSFORM   Sum(Total) AS SumOfTotal
SELECT      WeekCounter
FROM        MyQuery
GROUP BY    WeekCounter
PIVOT       Consumable_Type
```

I tried to combine the above two queries into one, but couldn't quite get there:

```
TRANSFORM   SUM(Total) AS Total_Consumables
SELECT      WeekCounter, Consumable_Type, Total
FROM
            (
                SELECT      WeekCounter
                            , Consumable_Type
                            , SUM(Consumable_Amount) AS Total
                FROM        WeekDefinition LEFT JOIN Consumables ON WeekDefinition.WeekStartDate<=Consumables.dDate AND
                                                                    WeekDefinition.WeekEndDate>=Consumables.dDate
                GROUP BY    WeekCounter, WeekID, Consumable_Type
                ORDER BY    WeekID  
            ) AS Q1
GROUP BY    WeekCounter, Consumable_Type, Total
PIVOT       Consumable_Type
```